# How to get React Native Pressable onPress to manipulate target

Tags: react-native, dom-manipulation, onpress, pressable

I have an array filled with the letters of the alphabet that I have turned into Pressable components.  My goal is to change the color of the letter clicked depending on some state.  React Native's Pressable onPress prop accepts a function with an event argument.  Sadly you can't simply do the classic event.target.style.color in order to manipulate the target like you can in vanilla js.  This is what I have tried so far:

```
const onPressLetter = (evt) => {
    let targetStyle = evt._dispatchInstances.memoizedProps.children[0].props.style;

    shadeLetter ? targetStyle.color = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)' : targetStyle.color = 'green';
}
```

The color change isn't taking place when clicked.  Console logging targetStyle before and after where we change the color even reflects that the style object has changed.  What am I doing wrong? How can i accomplish this in react native??

Keep in mind I dont want to use the style prop for Pressable because I want the color change to stay after click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Induce a bijection between letters and boolean states, which you can keep in a single state array. Provide the `onPressLetter` function with an index and toggle the corresponding state.

Here is a minimal example using map. In a real application, I would use a `FlatList`. The workflow stays the same.

```js
const alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

const Screen = (props) => {
    const [pressedLetters, setPressedLetters] = useState(alphabet.map(letter => false))
    
    function onPressLetter(i) {
        setPressedLetters(prev => prev.map((item, index) => index === i ? !item : item))
    }

    return (
            alphabet.map((item, index) => {
                return <Pressable onPress={() => onPressLetter(index)}>
                     <Text style={ {color: pressedLetters[index] ? 'green' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'}}>{item}</Text>
                </Pressable>
            })
    )
}
```

Comment: This solution works and is well thought out, but I wonder if there is a more optimized way to do this? Or better yet, Im really interested in how you can manipulate the DOM in a native environment like this. Ive tried googling it, but none of what I found works

Comment: What is „more optimized“ for you? The short answer to your question is, that this isn‘t possible in react native. You need to trigger a state change in order to visually change the view.

Comment: Im talking performance/ most efficient code when i say more optimized just because we have three map methods running, but i guess it wouldnt matter much unless we had a million letters to run through huh?

Comment: do you know if setNativeProps would work for this situation at all?

Comment: The first map functions runs only once on mount. This could be optimized by mapping over the alphabet array in the JSX instead over the state. Since every boolean is false anyway at the beginning, we could fill the state array after each press. The point of the state is triggering a rerendering, so this would work as well. The map function in the JSX should be replaced with a FlatList as mentioned in the answer. This is very performant even for large datasets. Thus, we have only one map left for the state. Instead of using an array as a state we might be able to use a hash table instead.

Comment: Hash each data point and the look up via the index would be in O(1). The overall “design” of the solution stays the same, though.

Comment: setNativeProps can work in certain scenarios. However, remember that Composite components are not backed by a native view. In general, there are very few cases where it makes sense to use setNativeProps. I’ve never tested the performance in comparison to the above, but now I’m curious ;).

Comment: haha let me know what your curiosity finds! Thanks for all your help david

Comment: im curious why you think a FlatList is better than just mapping in jsx? Im new to react-native, but ive come over with a decent amount of experience in react and to me mapping in the return is pretty normal

Comment: FlatList is optimized for larger datasets. Using map will render everything in the array even if it is not visible. FlatList on the other hand dynamically renders new data while scrolling. Most of the time we won’t notice any difference